# Script to Match Products with Images Named Using the Same SKU

Tags: wordpress-theming, woocommerce, wordpress, woothemes

I have a WordPress website using WooCommerce. I have all products with a unique SKU. I also have images uploaded on the server as well in a folder root/images named with each particular SKU.jpg (where SKU is changed by a number).

Has anyone managed to use or create a plugin or script which when run sets all matching images as default product image?

For example a Product with SKU 04563 has the default image set to root/images/04563.jpg when the plugin/script is run.

Comment: Sure, I've done that with a custom script. In short, you can use `glob` to grab all the file names. Then search for products ( `wp_query` using a meta_query parameter ) with a matching meta key ( `_sku` ). If found, copy the file to your wp images folder, then use `wp_handle_upload` and `wp_update_attachment_metadata` to generate a properly uploaded attachment. If successful, use `update_post_meta` to set that attachment as the product's thumbnail.

Comment: I'm still not that comfortable on WordPress - could you kindly show the script? Thanks :)